# How to fire an event in jquery when alt+tab or windows+d is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fire an event when when alt+tab or windows+d is pressed. Following is my code to give alert when mouse pointer is away from the browser window. But even if user presses alt+tab or Windows+D then also this event should get occur. Can anyone help me oin this regard, please? Folowing is my code for your reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script>
      var timer;
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).mouseleave(function () {
          //alert("Mouse is away");
          customAlert("your mouse is away");
        });
      });

      function customAlert(customText) {
        $("#popUp").html(customText);
        timer = setInterval(customAlert2, 5000);

        $("#popUp").dialog({
          dialogClass: "no-close",
          buttons: [{
                      text: "OK", click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        clearInterval(timer);
                      }
                    }]
        });
      }

      function customAlert2() {
        location.reload();
        $("#popUp2").dialog({
        dialogClass: "no-close",
        buttons: [{
                  text: "OK", click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                  }
                }]
        });
      }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My first Javascript program</h1>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <div id="popUp" title="First alert message"></div>
    <div id="popUp2" title="Second alert message">Time is over</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: JavaScript can only 'see' what is happening within the browser.

Comment: @PHPLover, did you find your answer?

Comment: I think you can be interested in HTML5 Visibility API https://davidwalsh.name/page-visibility

Answer (score 2):

[jwerty](https://keithamus.github.io/jwerty/) is a great plugin that allows you create functions for specific key combinations.

e.g.:

```
jwerty.key('ctrl+shift+P', function () { [...] });
```

Answer (score 2):

**attention** if you want to handle any keys that they registered by OS (for example: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> ) you **CAN NOT** do this by Jquery.

you need to assign your event to unregistered keys to fire your Event with Jquery.

you can try some code like blow to handle what you want handly

```
var keys = {};

 $(document).keydown(function (e) {
  keys[e.which] = true;
 });

 $(document).keyup(function (e) {
   delete keys[e.which];
});

if( (keys[91] && keys[68]) || (keys[18] && keys[9]) ) /*windows+d OR alt+tab*/
{ /* your code */}
```

---

or

use [jwerty](http://keithcirkel.co.uk/jwerty/) lib to do it. example code:

```
jwerty.key('ctrl+shift+P', function () { 
   // your code
});
```

and support commbinations:

```
jwerty.key('⌃+⇧+P/⌘+⇧+P', function () { 
   // your code
});
```

---

and There's a simple javaScript library [Mousetrap](http://craig.is/killing/mice) for handling keyboard shortcuts. Take a look at the example:

```
Mousetrap.bind('h', function() {
    // your code
});
```

OR

It also supports combinations:

```
Mousetrap.bind(['ctrl+h', 'ctrl+l'], function(e) {
    // your code
}
```

---

i hope it's useful for you.