# Capture ESC event when exiting full screen mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Requirement for me I have to show a particular div in full screen mode when I press a button 
and hide that div when the page comes back to normal mode.

I am able to achieve full screen mode with the code :-

```
function launchFullscreen(element) {
    if (element.requestFullscreen) {
        $('#bmessages').show();
        element.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        $('#bmessages').show();
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        $('#bmessages').show();
        element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
        $('#bmessages').show();
        element.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else {
        console.log("Fullscreen Unavailable");
    }
}
```

But I am unable to capture ESC or Deny event so that I can again hide that div? Please advice what I have to do?

Comment: May be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706070/how-to-detect-when-a-page-exits-fullscreen

Comment: @VenkatJanyavula ,I hope that this link is useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343309/how-to-fire-an-event-in-jquery-when-alttab-or-windowsd-is-pressed/20343513#20343513

Answer (score 70):

Chrome does not fire a key event when using esc to leave fullscreen. However, a fullscreenchange event IS fired.

```
document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', exitHandler);
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', exitHandler);
document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', exitHandler);
document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', exitHandler);

function exitHandler() {
    if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.webkitIsFullScreen && !document.mozFullScreen && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
        ///fire your event
    }
}
```

Comment: Very useful !! it helped me !!

Comment: Heads up: Maybe I'm seeing things, but when when Chrome dev tools is open, this fullscreen listener does not behave. With dev tools closed, I get expected correct behaviour. Context: In my web app, for testing I provide the user a button to open the app in fullscreen and visually, in template, I show state of both `document.fullscreenElement` and my own state tracking (e.g. a variable `enableFullscreen`). I get correct behaviour where both states match (ie "true true") when Chrome dev tools is closed, however with dev tools open, I get incorrect behaviour (ie "true false").

Answer (score 8):

As photicSphere points out, Chrome will not fire a key event when exiting full screen mode. You need to define an event listener that listens for a change to full screen mode, like this (this stuff isn't well standardised, so you need to listen for the events fired by different browsers):

```
        if (document.addEventListener) {
            document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
            document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
            document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
            document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', exitHandler, false);
        }
```

Then, when this event is fired by the browser, it will call an 'exitHandler' function that you define, and you can perform an action when the user is *exiting* full screen mode by doing the following:

```
    function exitHandler() {
        if (!document.webkitIsFullScreen && !document.mozFullScreen && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
            ... do something here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 27) { <DO YOUR WORK HERE> }   // esc
});
```

U may find this useful: [How to detect escape key press with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369593/how-to-detect-escape-key-press-with-javascript)

Comment: This simply doesn't work while "fullscreen mode" is enabled in Chrome. It works if you're out of "fullscreen mode" only.

Comment: `event.keyCode` is deprecated (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).  Don't use it anymore.  Instead, you should be using `KeyboardEvent.code` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)