# Angular - @HostListener('window:keydown.escape', ['$event']) not triggered when in full screen

Tags: angular

Is there any work-around to this problem?
I need to perform some actions **before** the fullscreen mode is exited (or at least before it has finished exiting), which is why the fullscreenchange event is of no use to me.
I tried listening for the escape button but ran into this problem.
Any alternative suggestion would be great too. Thanks!

Comment: It seem it's not possible to listen esc keydown event on chrome:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126106/capture-esc-event-when-exiting-full-screen-mode

Comment: Oh okay. I have used a timeout of 50ms to get around this for now. Would that be considered bad practice?